# Geometric interpretation of eigenvalues for a reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, reflection

[image]

In this question, I understand how to get the eigenvalues, but I don't really understand what they mean (in this context of a reflection). I'm mostly looking for how an eigenvalue of -1 means we have to take the transpose of the matrix here. Thanks!

Comment: Eigenvalue $-1$ means that for the corresponding eigenvector $v$ you have $Lv = -v$, i.e. $L$ is a reflection across the hyperplane orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: To add: the 2-dimensional hyperplane mentioned by Thomas is invariant under the reflection, so for those vectors $Lv = +v$, and you find a 2-dimensional eigenspace for eigenvalue 1.

Comment: As for the given answer: the eigenspace for value 1 is the orthogonal complement of the eigenspace of value -1, and a vector is in this hyperplane exactly when it is orthogonal to the given v. The kernel of the transpose of v is just a complicated way of saying that those vectors are orthogonal to v.

Comment: @Thomas Does that mean like having an eigenvalue of 1 would be a reflection to the left/right of v and an eigenvalue of -1 would be a reflection above/below v in R3? Sorry but just trying to get a really simple understanding here

Comment: An eigenvalue of $1$ means that the line generated by the corresponding vector is mapped identically onto itself (without being reversed). E.g. if you have a rotation around that eigen vector, of if the map is just trivial.

Comment: @Thomas when you say "corresponding vector", you mean a different vector from the given (1,0,2) vector, right? If it just maps onto itself, then what is the point of needing the given vector? Sorry if I'm not making sense, but I'm just confused about reflecting over a vector instead of a plane in R3 (which just seems arbitrary to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$In the hope a diagram helps, here's a generic decomposition $\Vec{v} = \Vec{v}_{1} + \Vec{v}_{-1}$ of a vector into eigenvectors of a reflection, and their respective images.

[image: Eigenspaces of a reflection]

Comment: Thanks! A couple of questions though:

1) is "v" in this case some random eigenvector, or the (1,0,2) vector by which we are reflecting over?

2) If 1 is not the case, then how exactly are representing the (1,0,2) vector in this diagram? The reflection stuff all makes sense, I'm just trying to get a grasp on trying to apply this to my problem

Comment: In the picture, $\Vec{v}$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$; the vector $(1, 0, 2)$ lies on the line $E_{-1}$ at an unspecified position, and $E_{1}$ is the plane orthogonal to $(1, 0, 2)$. The points are: (i) Every vector in the plane is fixed by the reflection $L$; (ii) Every vector on the line $E_{-1}$, i.e., every scalar multiple of $(1, 0, 2)$, is mapped by $L$ to its negative; (iii) The action of $L$ on an arbitrary vector $\Vec{v}$ may be seen by decomposing $\Vec{v}$ into eigenvectors of $L$ and letting $L$ act on the eigenvectors by scalar multiplication.

Comment: (i) What do you mean by "fixed"? If (what I think you're saying is) the orthogonal plane contains all vectors with an eigenvalue of 1, how would it not move? wouldn't it be "flipped" over still? (ii) How is every scalar multiple of (1,0,2) mapped it it's negative? Wouldn't literally the (1,0,2) be mapped to itself because it's not possible to reflect over itself (same logic applies for scalar multiples of it)? (iii) Makes sense

Comment: My apology: I mis-read the question. For your $L$, the space I'd labeled $E_{-1}$ was the $1$-eigenspace, while $E_{1}$ was the $-1$-eigenspace. The new diagram matches your question.